# Bootstrap Tree Menu - Collapse by Default Except Selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tree, menu

I'm using the tree collapse that comes with Twitter Bootstrap to build my menu.
The issue I'm having is that I want all menu lists to be collapsed by default except for the one we are currently on.
Here is an example of the menu: https://codeply.com/p/LqMr5BmovK

So for example, if the user is currently on the Bootstrap --> Buttons --> Colors page, then all top level menus should be collapsed except for the Bootstrap --> Buttons --> Colors, and the Forms under Buttons should be collapsed as well.
Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

After defining the on-click event, Toggle *everything* at the beginning to close or fold it.

```
//you already have this:
$('.tree-toggle').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
}); 
//add this line:
$('.tree-toggle').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(1000);
```

So we're telling it to "do everything" once at the beginning without waiting for anyone to click on it. You could change the toggle duration to whatever you want : in my case I want the user to get a glimpse of the many options available when the page loads, plus it gives a nice animation effect.

See working example: http://cssdeck.com/labs/fialo63a

To keep a selected one open, you could mark it with another class name and toggle that to open it after closing everything.

HTML:

```
<li><label class="tree-toggle nav-header selected">Bootstrap</label>
```

Javascript:

```
//add this line:
$('.selected').parent().children('ul.tree').toggle(200);
```

..so this might come off as a round-about way, but we're folding everything, and then unfolding the "selected" ones when we load the page.
Note: If your "selected" section that you want to keep open is not at top-level, then you're going to have to unfold all its parents also (ie, mark them also as "selected").

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing your tree using:

```
.siblings()
```

Here is an example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yT3H3/)